# In python using Regex, how do I insert a string after a string with a close-parenthesis character?

Tags: python, regex

I have lines of data like this:

```
(ABCD:0.00825830327156463345,(LKSDJF:0.00000254996576400768,SDFADS:0.00917039554517301569):0.16367666117488463562,OIUO:0.00401845774067355072):0.0;
((OIUO:0.00298782818816040099,SDFADS:0.00148583412998809050):0.27857371651571366522,ABCD:0.00188545323182991121,LKSDJF:0.00799482946501124843):0.0;
```

And I am trying to use regex to insert a string after every every "):randomfloatingpoint_number". Sometimes the number is following by a comma and sometimes by a semicolon.

This is the code I wrote:

```
        line = re.sub(r"):[0-9\.])",r"\1 " + string, line)
```

But I get an error message that the parenthesis are unbalanced:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "AssignFGbranches.py", line 31, in <module>
line = re.sub(r"):[0-9\.])",r"\1 " + string, line)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 151, in sub
return _compile(pattern, flags).sub(repl, string, count)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 242, in _compile
raise error, v # invalid expression
sre_constants.error: unbalanced parenthesis
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: I think you just need to escape the parens like this `/)`

Comment: You also don't need to escape `.` in a character class.

Comment: @matt, I never knew that :)

Comment: @JasonSperske all you ever really needed to know about regex: http://www.regular-expressions.info

Comment: @MattBall Thanks for that link-- I'll check it out! regex is so confusing to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two issues.  One is that the literal close parens needs to be escaped.  The other is that the open parens for the group was missing:

```
re.sub(r"(\):[0-9\.]+)",r"\1 " + string, line1)
```

Comment: Thanks, this works perfectly... I still have trouble understanding regex. Hopefully the link Matt posted in the comments to my question will help. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the brackets. Also, there is no number that is immediately followed by a closing brace. You may want something like this:

```
(\):[0-9.]+[;,])
```

This will match the following:

554517301569`):0.16367666117488463562,`OIUO